# How to initialise Google drive using GoogleCedentials instead of the deprecated GoogleCedential

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have java code to connect to google drive using a service account, this works:

```java
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new GsonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("sa.json"))
                .createScoped(List.of(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .createDelegated("foo@bar.com");

return new Drive.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("my-drive-app")
                .build();
```

However i'm getting a deprecation warning that `GoogleCredential` is deprecated and that i should use `GoogleCredentials` (note the extra s at the end) from the `google-auth-library` instead.

I can initialise `GoogleCredentials` like this:

```java
GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("sa.json"))
                .createScoped(List.of(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .createDelegated("foo@bar.com");
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to initialise the drive service using this new `GoogleCredentials` object. Passing it in in place of the credential object gives a compiler error and all of the official google drive java documentation refers the now deprecated method.

Can someone tell me how to initialise google drive using the new credentials object?

Versions I'm using:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.32.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>1.32.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev20210919-1.32.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To connect to Google Drive use the [HttpCredentialsAdapter](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/main/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/http/HttpCredentialsAdapter.java) to make the connection from `GoogleCredentials` to `GoogleCredential`.

Sample:

```java
return new Drive.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential))
                .setApplicationName("my-drive-app")
                .build();
```

Comment: Your example shows me how to initialise a google storage connection to a bucket. That I already knew. However this method doesn't work when connecting to google drive. (where my google docs, sheets, slides, etc live).

Everything GCP related is well documented, however I'm looking on how to initialise a connection to google drive.

I looked for a "DriveOptions" class, but that one doesn't exist as far as i can tell.

Comment: Also, i have the `GoogleCredential` method working. However that one is clearly marked as deprecated. Is using a deprecated API the official recommended way to do this?

Comment: To be more specific, the Builder in the java api for drive needs a `com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer` to build, i can't figure out how to turn `GoogleCredentials` into one.

Comment: I think I understand your issue now. The best in your situation is to use  the [HttpCredentialsAdapter](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/main/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/http/HttpCredentialsAdapter.java)

Comment: That was my missing piece, thanks!