# Migrate to GoogleCredentials from GoogleCredential

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

Currently, I am using the following implementation but the code says GoogleCredential is deprecated.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .build();
            credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
```

I checked and GoogleCredentials or other google-auth-library classes are supposed to be used. However, all of them seem to require a service account. GoogleCredential is working for me without a service account. Just had to create oauth credentials. I have also generated the refresh tokens but not sure how to use them with the new library. What should I be using here? The goal is to just allow a single user(our backend code) to access google api.

I don't see any other questions for java where this was actually answered.

Edit - Posting my entire set up based on the comment updates-

```
public Credentials getCredentials() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        try(InputStream in = getCredentialsAsInputStream()) {

            if (in == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
            }
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

            String clientId = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId();
            String clientSecret = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret();

            Credentials credential = UserCredentials.newBuilder()
                    .setClientId(clientId)
                    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
                    .build();

            return credential;
```

And for setting up the drive

```
public Drive getDriveService() {
        try {
            Credentials credential = getCredentials();
            HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential);
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, httpRequestInitializer)
                    .setApplicationName(DRIVE_API_APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .setHttpRequestInitializer(httpRequest -> {

                        httpRequestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
                        httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(2 * 60000);  // 2 minutes connect timeout
                        httpRequest.setReadTimeout(2 * 60000);  // 2 minutes read timeout

                    })
                    .build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e){
            log.error("Error creating drive service class : {}", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`google-auth-library`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/main/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.java) as there it defines the class `GoogleCredentials`:

```
Google Credentials = new GoogleCredentials.Builder()
            .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .build();
            credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
```

You can as well check the Java documentation for [`GoogleCredentials`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/1.1.0/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html)

It seems that you are trying to use the `Drive API` so you may as well check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555366/how-to-initialise-google-drive-using-googlecedentials-instead-of-the-deprecated) about connecting to the Drive service.

Comment: Apparently, builder has protected access so this method did not work. I also noticed a GoogleCredentials.newBuilder() however, that did not come with an option for ".setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)". Appreciate the other thread as well. I will certainly try it out but as mentioned earlier, I am not using a service account.

Comment: Does it make sense to use UserCredentials class? I can see that it has an option for setting refresh tokens